# Young Girl Fantasy Series (I think?)

Tags: story-identification, magical-items

When I was in middle school a few years ago, I read this fantasy series that centered around a couple of modern girls who were able to cross over into this fantasy world.

I'm not 100% sure but I think they may have gotten some magical stones and the idea was for them to fight against shadows taking over the land or something. One girl brought her flute with her into the fantasy land and scared a unicorn with it (by accident).

I'm pretty sure it was American with English, and I'm guessing it'd be the 2000s.I know that the girls received magical gemstones that gave them different powers, for instance one girl was able to heal.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. Is there any chance you could supply some additional basic material, like the country, language, an estimated year, and/or a description of the cover? Any additional details might help.

Comment: Hello! I'm pretty sure it was American with English, and I'm guessing it'd be the 2000s. I honestly don't remember anything about what the cover looked like. I know that the girls received magical gemstones that gave them different powers, for instance one girl was able to heal.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69463/teenagers-taken-from-their-worlds-attracted-to-colored-gems-which-give-them-spe (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're describing the "[Diadem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_%28series%29)" series of books by John Peel

- **Magical portals** - Check
- **Modern girls travelling to a magical realm** - Check
- **Magical [Gemstones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_%28series%29#Gemstones)** - Check (including one with healing properties)
- **Baddies called "the Shadows"** - Check.

The only thing I can't place is the flute but there are definitely **unicorns** present

> *Diadem chronicles the adventures of three teenagers from very different worlds. Score is a streetwise New Yorker, Renald lives in a Medieval world where she readies herself for battle, and Pixel is confined to a one-room world of Virtual Reality. But now they all exist in the Diadem, the circuit of all worlds where their awesome purpose unfolds*
>
> *After her guise as Renald was ruined by Oracle, she planned to run away. As she was leaving, the Shadows inhabited a group of soldiers sent by the border lords to kidnap her and hold her for ransom but she was rescued and brought to Treen by Rahn, a leopard Bestial. After reaching Dondar, she bonded with Flame, her unicorn friend, and the two are very close. Flame is the daughter of Thunder and Nova, and she seems to be the only person Helaine will open up to. Helaine's main magic ability is the power to foresee trouble. Her powers with the gemstones are levitation, communication, earth, and shape-shifting.*